# Replacing Multi-Dimension for-loop with range-based for-loop

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

I have a Vec3 class.
What is the best way to replace a loop like

```
for (int x = 20; x < 25; x++)
    for (int y = 40; y < 45; y++)
        for (int z = 2; z < 4; z++) doStuff({x,y,z});
```

with something like this:

```
for(Vec3 v: Vec3range({20,40,2}, {25,45,4}))
    doStuff(v);
```

without any runtime costs?

Comment: See these questions and answers to them: [TMP: how to generalize a Cartesian Product of Vectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13813007/3043539), [For loop over template arguments/types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015710/for-loop-over-template-arguments-types?lq=1) and [Avoid nested for-loops when searching parameter space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21186904/3043539).

Comment: Vec3range needs to be custom container type (with begin, end, ect) with a custom iterator. However, because this necessitates intermediate classes with changing internal variables, this WILL prevent the compiler from being able to unroll the loops, so it may be slower in the long run. And honestly, IMHO it is much less readable.

Comment: I'm with @MadScienceDreams on this - vectors aren't typically manipulated in this manner, so the approach (though more concise) doesn't make a lot of sense without explanation. IMO the best option is to play with your code formatting if you don't like the way the loops read and/or create a macro to make this sort of loop if you need them frequently and don't like doing a lot of typing.

Comment: I just wrote a working solution, but wow is it ugly. And as per @MadScienceDreams, it definitely will be slower anyway. Slow + Ugly? Sounds like a winner!

Comment: @Conduit It's for creating elements in a 3d map, there were lots of loops like this for creating the floor, etc. ([github](https://github.com/phiresky/noeuclid/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about the simplest implementation I could manage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

using tuple_3d = tuple<int, int, int>;

struct range_3d;

struct range_3d_iterator
{
  const range_3d& c;
  tuple_3d i;

  bool operator!=(const range_3d_iterator& other)
  { return get<0>(i) != get<0>(other.i) && get<1>(i) != get<1>(other.i) && get<2>(i) != get<2>(other.i); }

  tuple_3d operator*() const
  { return make_tuple(get<0>(i), get<1>(i), get<2>(i)); }

  const range_3d_iterator& operator++();
};

struct range_3d
{
  tuple_3d s;
  tuple_3d e;

  range_3d_iterator begin() const
  { return { *this, s }; }

  range_3d_iterator end() const
  { return { *this, e }; }
};

const range_3d_iterator& range_3d_iterator::operator++()
{
  ++get<2>(i);
  if (get<2>(i) == get<2>(c.e))
  {
    get<2>(i) = get<2>(c.s);
    ++get<1>(i);
    if (get<1>(i) == get<1>(c.e))
    {
      get<1>(i) = get<1>(c.s);
      ++get<0>(i);
    }
  }
  return *this;
}

int main(void)
{
  for (auto&& v : range_3d{ make_tuple(20, 40, 2), make_tuple(25, 45, 4) })
    cout << get<0>(v) << ' ' << get<1>(v) << ' ' << get<2>(v) << endl;  
}
```

The naming is a bit crap, but that aside, the concept is simple. The `range_3d` is a simple class which supports `begin()`, `end()` to get the range for loop to work, then the "smartness" is in the `range_3d_iterator` which will iterate the tuple. Given the way I've used the tuple here, it's trivial to extend to arbitary dimensions...

TBH, the original for loop is pretty clear... IMO!

Comment: Thanks! This works well. Not sure if I'm going to use this or just keep the normal loop, or maybe write a macro.

Answer (score 2):

For this, I wrote an *iterating* and a *combining* adaptor in my [functional library ***fn***](https://bitbucket.org/leemes/fn):

```
#include <fn.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using std; using fn;

    for (auto &&values : combine(seq(20,25), seq(40,45), seq(2,4))) {
        int x, y, z; 
        tie(x, y, z) = values;
        cout << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << "\n";
        // or in your case: doStuff({x, y, z});
    }
}
```

Output:

```
20, 40, 2
20, 40, 3
20, 41, 2
20, 41, 3
...
24, 43, 2
24, 43, 3
24, 44, 2
24, 44, 3
```

Here, `seq(a, b)` returns an implicit range which **iterates through the values `[a, b)`** (i.e. the first is inclusive, the second exclusive). (A third parameter can specify the step and more complex alternatives exist for more control over the iteration.)

The function `combine(ranges...)` returns an implicit range which **iterates over all combinations** of the given ranges (where the first is considered the "most significant" one, similar to your "outer-most" loop). Its iterator dereferences to a `std::tuple` holding the current combination.

This tuple is then tied in the loop body to some variables. (Sadly, there is no "auto-tie" for the range-based for loop like `for(tie(auto x, auto y, auto z) : ...)`.)

---

### Implementation:

#### [`seq()`](https://bitbucket.org/leemes/fn/src/0e2bfec14f7be0f450beab8a06e722a8baedc2ce/iterate.h?at=master#cl-33)

That's quite easy: it is a function returning an adaptor object which has `begin()` and `end()` functions. They return a custom iterator which increments the current value in `operator++` and returns it in `operator*`.

#### [`combine()`](https://bitbucket.org/leemes/fn/src/f7327cc05048c0e2d1386deef6af708f39ca6072/combine.h?at=master#cl-19)

This is more interesting: it returns an adaptor object which holds the ranges being provided as the arguments to `combine` in a tuple member. The iterator of this adaptor holds iterators to the wrapped ranges in a tuple member, but three times: the current position, the begin and the end, you soon see why.

The `operator++` of the iterator is most likely the most interesting one: it's implemented recursively using variadic templates in [`variadic_ops.h`, `va_next_combination()`](https://bitbucket.org/leemes/fn/src/7af219e7d7b2c05dc9a0b3885b9c981875f6b31f/variadic_ops.h?at=master#cl-34) and it is given triplets of iterators (for each range the current, begin, and end):

```
// base case
inline bool va_next_combination() {
    return true;
}

// recursive case
template<typename Head, typename ...Tail>
inline bool va_next_combination(std::tuple<Head&,Head&,Head&> && curr_and_begin_and_end, std::tuple<Tail&,Tail&,Tail&> &&...t) {
    // advance the "tail" to its next combination and check if it had an overflow
    if (va_next_combination(std::forward<std::tuple<Tail&,Tail&,Tail&>>(t)...)) {
        // advance the "head" iterator
        ++std::get<0>(curr_and_begin_and_end);
        // check if the "head" just overflow
        bool at_end = (std::get<0>(curr_and_begin_and_end) == std::get<2>(curr_and_begin_and_end));
        // if it did, put it back to the beginning and report the overflow
        if (at_end) std::get<0>(curr_and_begin_and_end) = std::get<1>(curr_and_begin_and_end);
        return at_end;
    } else {
        // "tail" didn't overflow, so we do nothing and no overflow should be reported
        return false;
    }
}
```

Starting from the right most iterator in the set, it increments the iterator. If it just reached the end of the range, it reports that as the return value of the recursive function. The next iterator checks that value, if it is true itself needs to advance (otherwise not) as well as "reset" the iterator next to the right (i.e. "wrap around" its overflow), and finally it reports the same information to the next to the left.

That's basically how mechanical counters work, if you start at the "if"-condition in the deepest recursion level.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<size_t N>
using indexes=std::array<size_t,N>;

template<size_t N>
void advance( indexes<N>& in, indexes<N-1> const& limit, size_t amt=1 );
```

which finds the index amt further along, wrapping around at limit.

Then write a range object.  It stores the limit and two iterators, b and e.  `begin` returns `b`, and `end` `e`.

The iterators have a pointer to the range they come from and an array of values.  They `++` via `next` above.  Write the usual forward iterator boilerplate.

Your function probably should be:

```
template<size_t N>
multi_range_t<N> multi_range( indexes<N> start, indexes<N> finish );
```

which requires you to pass `N`.

Finally write a copy ctor for `Vec3` from `std::array<3,T>`.

You can probably make it a touch easier by making it 3 instead of `N`, but only a touch.