# Is there a name for this tuple-creation idiom?

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, c++14, generic-lambda

On the [**Boost mailinglist**](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2014/06/214213.php), the following clever trick to create a tuple-like entity was recently posted by @LouisDionne:

```
#include <iostream>

auto list = [](auto ...xs) { 
    return [=](auto access) { return access(xs...); }; 
}; 

auto length = [](auto xs) { 
    return xs([](auto ...z) { return sizeof...(z); }); 
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << length(list(1, '2', "3")); // 3    
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11edc69bc10817e5).

The cleverness is that `list` is a lambda taking a variadic parameter-list as input, and returning a lambda as an output that will take another lambda to act on its input. Similarly, `length` is a lambda taking a list-like entity, to which it will supply the variadic `sizeof...` operator to the list's original input parameters. The `sizeof...` operator is wrapped inside a lambda so that it can be passed to the `list`.

**Question**: is there a name for this tuple-creation idiom? Perhaps from a functional programming language where higher-order functions are more commonly used.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific name for this, but you might want to look at lambda calculus. They define all sorts of stuff using only lambdas, but there are no varargs there. Your example is a bit like Church Pair ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_pairs ), so I guess you could call it Church tuple?

Comment: @zch I'm somewhat reminded of your [tmp cartesian product](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13841673/819272) trick

Comment: I was reading the code again. Your `list` is a monad, isn't? A function expecting other function to complete the computation http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad

Comment: Ignore the tuple for now.  Then `List:X->(X->Y)->Y`.  Which should be easier to find.

Comment: Could you perhaps show a more useful application of this idiom? To me this looks utterly pointless/useless and it's not obvious to me what a useful example might be.

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm having trouble understanding all the details, but there is an entire [library Boost.Hana](https://github.com/ldionne/hana) (proposed by the author of the quoted code above) based on such tricks.

Comment: @Manu343726 you can make monads of *any* implementation of a list if you tack the rest of the monad to it. Just like you can make a lot of other things based on lists if you tack the rest of the thing to it. Does that make "it's a monad!" a more useful answer than "it's a functor!"?

Comment: That's a form of *continuation passing style* (the `list` function returns a function taking a continuation in argument).

Comment: @AlexandreC. feel free to add an answer!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think this is a subtle implementation of a Monad-like thing, specifically something in the same spirit of the continuation monad.

Monads are a functional programming construction used to simulate state between different steps of a computation (Remember that a functional language is stateless).
What a monad does is to chain different functions, creating a *"computation pipeline"* where each step knows about the current state of the computation.

Monads have two primary pilars:

- A return function, which takes a value and returns it in a Monad-ready form.
- A bind function, which takes a Monad-ready value (From the previous pipeline step) and unwraps it to its original from to pass the value to the next step.

[The Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)) has very good examples and explanations about monads.

Let me rewrite the given C++14 code:

```
auto list = []( auto... xs ) 
{ 
    return [=]( auto access ) { return access(xs...); };
};
```

I think here we identify the `return` function of a monad: Takes the value and returns it in a Monadic way.
Specifically, this return returns a functor (In the mathematical sense, not a C++ functor) which goes from the "tuple" category to the variadic pack category.

```
auto pack_size = [](auto... xs ) { return sizeof...(xs); };
```

`pack_size` is just a normal function. It would be used in a pipeline to do some work.

```
auto bind = []( auto xs , auto op ) 
{
    return xs(op);
};
```

And `length` is only a non-generic version of something near to the monad `bind` operator, an operator which takes a monadic value from a previous pipeline step, and bypasses it to the specified function (Function which really does the work). That function is the functionality done by this computation step.

Finally your call could be rewritten as:

```
auto result = bind(list(1,'2',"3"), pack_size);
```

So, ***whats the name of this tuple creation idiom?*** Well, I think this could be called "*monad-like tuples*", since its not exactly a monad, but the tuple representation and expansion works in a similar way, remaining to the Haskell continuation monad.

### Edit: More fun

Just for the shake of funny C++ programming, I have followed exploring this monad-like thing. You could find some examples [here](https://gist.github.com/Manu343726/fb57746274fffc043c2a).

Comment: And does this monad have a special name?

Comment: While perhaps this might be coincidentally an instance of a monad when supplied with bind function, it is surely not the only monad nor does it represent all monads in any way, so I don't think 'monad' is right name for this idiom. Secondly, any list implementation can be made a monad with appropriate `bind` and `return`. Finally, your `bind` doesn't seem to be even type-correct really. For example, it seems it cannot be chained.

Comment: @zch Of course this is not exactly a monad, what Im trying to explain here is that this thing has the same subtle form of a monad, and (as the monad) could be used in a completely generic way. The  gem here is the return function of the "monad", which allows to create a tuple, pass it around, and extract its contents directly, with no indices trick. Thats a good one

Comment: @zch It is a manifestation of the continuation monad. Therefore, it is by all means 'all the monads'

Comment: How is `length` a non-generic version of a `bind` if it doesn't return an instance of the same monad?

Comment: I don't know why you keep not writing such corrections in the answer. (But, by then, will it be a useful answer to the question "Is there a name for this tuple-creation idiom?"?)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes as I commented before, this thing is not technically a monad, but something in the same way. Specifically, this thing could be interpreted as an (incomplete) continuation monad, as Sumant explainedon his answer.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yep, I was wrong (and you where correct) when clarifying the answer through comments instead of editting the answer itself. I have edited the answer to make clear that this thing is not exactly a monad, but a thing remaining the continuation monad for tuples instead. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 19):

I would call this idiom **tuple-continuator** or more generally, **monadic-continuator**. It is most definitely an instance of a continuation monad. A great introduction for continuation monad for C++ programmers is [here](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2012/06/asynchronous-api-in-c-and-the-continuation-monad). In essence, the `list` lambda above takes a value (a variadic parameter-pack) and returns a simple 'continuator' (the inner closure). This continuator, when given a callable (called `access`), passes the parameter pack into it and returns whatever that callable returns.

Borrowing from the FPComplete blogpost, a continuator is more or less like the following.

```
template<class R, class A>
struct Continuator {
    virtual ~Continuator() {}
    virtual R andThen(function<R(A)> access) = 0;
};
```

The `Continuator` above is abstract--does not provide an implementation. So, here is a simple one.

```
template<class R, class A>
struct SimpleContinuator : Continuator<R, A> {
    SimpleContinuator (A x) : _x(x) {}
    R andThen(function<R(A)> access) {
        return access(_x);
    }
    A _x;
};
```

The `SimpleContinuator` accepts one value of type `A` and passes it on to `access` when `andThen` is called. The `list` lambda above is essentially the same. It is more general. Instead of a single value, the inner closure captures a parameter-pack and passes it to the `access` function. Neat!

Hopefully that explains what it means to be a continuator. but what does it mean to be a monad? Here is a good [introduction](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html) using pictures.

I think the `list` lambda is also a list monad, which is implemented as a continuation monad. Note that [continuation monad is the mother of all monads](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/12/mother-of-all-monads.html). I.e., you can implement any monad with a continuation monad. Of course, list monad is not out of reach.

As a parameter-pack is quite naturally a 'list' (often of heterogeneous types), it makes sense for it to work like a list/sequence monad. The `list` lambda above is a very interesting way of converting C++ parameter-packs to a monadic structure. Therefore, operations can be chained one after another.

The `length` lambda above, however, is a bit disappointing because it breaks the monad and the nested lambda inside simply returns an integer. There is arguably a better way to write the length 'getter' as shown below.

**----Functor----**

Before we can say the list lambda is a monad, we have to show that it is a functor. I.e., fmap must be written for list.

The list lambda above serves as the creator of the functor from a parameter pack---essentially it serves as the `return`. That created functor keeps the parameter-pack with itself (capture) and it allows 'access' to it provided you give a callable that accepts a variable number of arguments. Note that the callable is called EXACTLY-ONCE.

Lets write fmap for such a functor.

```
auto fmap = [](auto func) { 
    return [=](auto ...z) { return list(func(z)...); };
};
```

The type of the func must be (a -> b). I.e., in C++ speak,

```
template <class a, class b>
b func(a);
```

The type of fmap is `fmap: (a -> b) -> list[a] -> list[b]` I.e., in C++ speak,

```
template <class a, class b, class Func>
list<b> fmap(Func, list<a>);
```

I.e., fmap simply maps list-of-a to a list-of-b.

Now you can do

```
auto twice = [](auto i) { return 2*i; };
auto print = [](auto i) { std::cout << i << " "; return i;};
list(1, 2, 3, 4)
    (fmap(twice))
    (fmap(print)); // prints 2 4 6 8 on clang (g++ in reverse)
```

Therefore, it is a functor.

**----Monad----**

Now, lets try to write a `flatmap` (a.k.a. `bind`, `selectmany`)

Type of flatmap is `flatmap: (a -> list[b]) -> list[a] -> list[b].`

I.e., given a function that maps a to a list-of-b and a list-of-a, flatmap return a list-of-b. Essentially, it takes each element from list-of-a, calls func on it, receives (potentially empty) list-of-b one-by-one, then concatenates all the list-of-b, and finally returns the final list-of-b.

Here's an implementation of flatmap for list.

```
auto concat = [](auto l1, auto l2) {
    auto access1 = [=](auto... p) {
      auto access2 = [=](auto... q) {
        return list(p..., q...);
      };
      return l2(access2);
    };
    return l1(access1);
};

template <class Func>
auto flatten(Func)
{
  return list(); 
}

template <class Func, class A>
auto flatten(Func f, A a)
{
  return f(a); 
}

template <class Func, class A, class... B>
auto flatten(Func f, A a, B... b)
{
  return concat(f(a), flatten(f, b...));
}

auto flatmap = [](auto func) {
  return [func](auto... a) { return flatten(func, a...); };
};
```

Now you can do a lot of powerful things with a list. For example,

```
auto pair  = [](auto i) { return list(-i, i); };
auto count = [](auto... a) { return list(sizeof...(a)); };
list(10, 20, 30)
    (flatmap(pair))
    (count)
    (fmap(print)); // prints 6.
```

The count function is a monad-perserving operation because it returns a list of single element. If you really want to get the length (not wrapped in a list) you have to terminate the monadic chain and get the value as follows.

```
auto len = [](auto ...z) { return sizeof...(z); }; 
std::cout << list(10, 20, 30)
                 (flatmap(pair))
                 (len);
```

If done right, the [collection pipeline](http://martinfowler.com/articles/collection-pipeline/) pattern (e.g., `filter`, `reduce`) can now be applied to C++ parameter-packs. Sweet!

**----Monad Laws----**

Let's make sure the `list` monad satisfies all three [monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws).

```
auto to_vector = [](auto... a) { return std::vector<int> { a... }; };

auto M = list(11);
std::cout << "Monad law (left identity)\n";
assert(M(flatmap(pair))(to_vector) == pair(11)(to_vector));

std::cout << "Monad law (right identity)\n";
assert(M(flatmap(list))(to_vector) == M(to_vector));

std::cout << "Monad law (associativity)\n";
assert(M(flatmap(pair))(flatmap(pair))(to_vector) == 
       M(flatmap([=](auto x) { return pair(x)(flatmap(pair)); }))(to_vector));
```

All asserts are satisfied.

**----Collection Pipeline----**

Although the above 'list' lambda is provably a monad and shares characteristics of the proverbial 'list-monad', it is quite unpleasant. Especially, because the behavior of common [collection pipeline](http://martinfowler.com/articles/collection-pipeline/) combinators, such as `filter` (a.k.a `where`) does not meet common expectations.

The reason is just how C++ lambdas work. Each lambda expression produces a function object of a unique type. Therefore, `list(1,2,3)` produces a type that has nothing to do with `list(1)` and an empty list, which in this case would be `list()`.

The straight-forward implementation of `where` fails compilation because in C++ a function can not return two different types.

```
auto where_broken = [](auto func) {
  return flatmap([func](auto i) { 
      return func(i)? list(i) : list(); // broken :-(
  }); 
};
```

In the above implementation, func returns a boolean. It's a predicate that says true or false for each element. The ?: operator does not compile.

So, a different trick can be used to allow continuation of the collection pipeline. Instead of actually filtering the elements, they are simply flagged as such---and that's what makes it unpleasant.

```
auto where_unpleasant = [](auto func) {
  return [=](auto... i) { 
      return list(std::make_pair(func(i), i)...);
  }; 
};
```

The `where_unpleasant` gets the job done but unpleasantly...

For example, this is how you can filter negative elements.

```
auto positive = [](auto i) { return i >= 0; };
auto pair_print = [](auto pair) { 
  if(pair.first) 
     std::cout << pair.second << " "; 
  return pair; 
};
list(10, 20)
    (flatmap(pair))
    (where_unpleasant(positive))
    (fmap(pair_print)); // prints 10 and 20 in some order
```

**----Heterogeneous Tuples----**

So far the discussion was about homogeneous tuples. Now lets generalize it to true tuples. However, `fmap`, `flatmap`, `where` take only one callback lambda. To provide multiple lambdas each working on one type, we can overload them. For example,

```
template <class A, class... B>
struct overload : overload<A>, overload<B...> {
  overload(A a, B... b) 
      : overload<A>(a), overload<B...>(b...) 
  {}  
  using overload<A>::operator ();
  using overload<B...>::operator ();
};

template <class A>
struct overload<A> : A{
  overload(A a) 
      : A(a) {} 
  using A::operator();
};

template <class... F>
auto make_overload(F... f) {
  return overload<F...>(f...);   
}

auto test = 
   make_overload([](int i) { std::cout << "int = " << i << std::endl; },
                 [](double d) { std::cout << "double = " << d << std::endl; });
test(10); // int 
test(9.99); // double
```

Let's use the overloaded lambda technique to process a heterogeneous tuple continuator.

```
auto int_or_string = 
        make_overload([](int i) { return 5*i; },
                      [](std::string s) { return s+s; });
    list(10, "20")
        (fmap(int_or_string))
        (fmap(print)); // prints 2020 and 50 in some order
```

Finally, **[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df4b3b9d86983482)**

Comment: "then merges all the list[b];" What exactly do you mean by "merge" here? Join? Union? Or something else?

Comment: Either you wanted to write `SimpleContinuator` in place of `Return` , Or `Return` in place of `SimpleContinuator`. In other words, a class named `SimpleContinuator` cannot have a constructor called `Return`. Or a class whose constructor is `Return` cannot be named `SimpleContinuator`. Please fix this to avoid confusion.

Comment: This answer is dated and only about 75% correct. for a correct, more complete answer please visit: http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2014/08/fun-with-lambdas-c14-style-part-3.html

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a form of [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

The rough idea of CPS is this: instead of having a function (say `f`) return some value, you give to `f` another argument, which is a function, called a *continuation*. Then, `f` calls this continuation with the return value instead of returning. Let's take an example:

```
int f (int x) { return x + 42; }
```

becomes

```
void f (int x, auto cont) { cont (x + 42); }
```

The call is a tail call, and can be optimized into a jump (this is why TCO is mandated in some languages, like Scheme, whose semantics rely on some form of transformation into CPS).

Another example:

```
void get_int (auto cont) { cont (10); }
void print_int (int x) { printf ("%d", x), }
```

You can now do `get_int (std::bind (f, _1, print_int))` to print 54. Note that all the continuation calls are *always* tail calls (the call to `printf` is also a continuation call).

A well-known example is asynchronous callbacks (AJAX calls in javascript for instance): you pass a continuation to a routine executing in parallel.

Continuations can be composed (and [form a monad](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/12/mother-of-all-monads.html), in case you're interested), as in the above example. In fact [it is possible](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/5753/AIM-443.pdf) to transform a (functional) program entirely into CPS, so that every call is a tail call (and then you need no stack to run the program !).