# Higher-order functions with templates?

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I've been programming in Clojure (a functional language) for a while now, and I have to use C++ for a class. I've been trying to use some of the functionality I've enjoyed in Clojure (e.g., higher-order functions, lambdas, argument threading, dynamic typing, etc.) but I've been running into some brick walls.

Firstly, I've implemented a function `get` which takes two arguments:

1. a collection (vector, list, hash map, etc.), and
2. an index

and returns the element at that index.

I've also implemented a function `conj` which takes two arguments:

1. a collection (vector, list, queue, etc.), and
2. an element/object (of whatever type the collection is)

and returns the collection with the element added. In the case of vectors, this is largely the same as `push_back`.

Now, I want to be able to "forward" or "thread" the arguments using higher-order functions like so:

```
using std::vector;
vector<double> my_vec;

forward(my_vec,    // take "my_vec"
        conj(0.1), // "push" the value of 0.1 to the back of "my_vec"
        get(0),    // retrieve the first value
        inc);      // increment that value
```

It's the same as `inc(get(conj(my_vec, 0.1), 0);`, but a lot (!) more readable.

The return value of `forward` in this case should be 1.1.

In order to get the `forward` function to work, the arguments after the initial argument need to all be higher-order functions. That is, they need to work analogous to the following:

```
template<typename Func>
Func get(int i){
  return [i](vector<boost::any> coll)
           -> boost::optional<boost::any> {
             return get(coll, i);
           };
}
```

However, the compiler can't deduce the type of the lambda function to be returned. Also, my guess, based on my extremely limited experience with `boost::any`, is that it won't be able to convert a `vector<double>` to `vector<boost::any>`, despite the apparent claims of `boost::any` that it can act as a substitute for virtually any type.

I want the `get` function to be general, so I don't want to use `boost::function<double (vector <double>, int)>`, or any similarly specific typing.

Also, I'm using `boost::optional` instead of `vector` to return `null_ptr` if the index requested from `get` is out of bounds.

As it stands, here's how my `forward` function looks:

```
template <typename T1>
optional<T1> forward (T1 expr1){
  return expr1;
}
template <typename T1, typename T2>
optional<T1> forward (T1 expr1, T2 expr2){
  return forward(expr2(expr1));
}
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
optional<T1> forward (T1 expr1, T2 expr2, T3 expr3){
  return forward(expr2(expr1), expr3);
}
```

***etc. ...***

Any ideas on how to get this `forward` function to work?

I'm also pretty sure there's a more efficient way to implement it than doing the arity-overloading as I have.

Comment: Lookup monadic functions and continuators, a functional programming concept. [See how it is implemented in C++11.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25342660/701092)

Comment: What compiler and version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an addition to Horstling's answer, actually `forward` can be implemented much easier:

```
template <typename Value>
Value forward(Value v) {
    return v;
}

template <typename Value, typename Func, typename... Funcs>
auto forward(Value v, Func f, Funcs... fs) -> decltype(forward(f(v), fs...)) {
    return forward(f(v), fs...);
}
```

And C++14 sweetens things even a little bit more:

```
template <typename Value>
Value forward(Value v) {
    return v;
}

template <typename Value, typename Func, typename... Funcs>
decltype(auto) forward(Value v, Func f, Funcs... fs) {
    return forward(f(v), fs...);
}
```

Take a look at the full code  [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/039905c5deff8dcf) (Coliru appears to support boost)

Answer (score 2):

That's what I can come up with:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/039905c5deff8dcf

Instead of lambdas I used fully fledged functors in three different variants. It supports your example and does not require type erase or such (e.g. boost::any or std::function).

```
boost::optional<double> result = forward(my_vec, conj(0.1), get(0), inc);
```

Also, the `forward` function is implemented as variadic template, allowing any number of functions.

The code is unpolished, but maybe it can give some inspiration.

*EDIT: [Anton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25573895/3989746) is absolutely right, my implementation of forward was unnecessarily complicated. The link above now points to his revised version of the code.*