# Lambda-Over-Lambda in C++14

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

How following recursive lambda call ends/terminates ?

```
#include <cstdio>

auto terminal = [](auto term)            // <---------+  
{                                        //           |
    return [=] (auto func)               //           |  ???
    {                                    //           |
        return terminal(func(term));     // >---------+
    };
};


auto main() -> int
{
    auto hello =[](auto s){ fprintf(s,"Hello\n"); return s; };
    auto world =[](auto s){ fprintf(s,"World\n"); return s; };


    terminal(stdout)
            (hello)
            (world) ;

    return 0;

}
```

What am I missing over here ?

<sup>[`Running code`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edecb386f07ada7d)</sup>

Comment: Nice one for this list: http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/helloworld.html

Comment: Actually, I'm interested in how this (is/can be) called, so I posted a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619769/how-is-this-c14-construct-called

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25338795/596781)?

Comment: Perhaps you intended `return terminal(func)(term);` instead of `return terminal(func(term));`? Note that `terminal` needs to be called with arguments *twice* before it does anything.

Comment: Oh my god, this: "auto main() -> int" is awful. It's not fun to try to use new tools when the old one are already perfect for the job. Or is "int main()" so 2010 ?

Comment: Note that the definition of `terminal` didn't capture the variable `terminal` which is used by the anonymous lambda returned by `terminal`. But it works ... it is because `terminal` is defined at the namespace level, which can be accessed by anyone, including the anonymous lambda. However, if it was defined in a function scope, this code wouldn't even compile; and the fix would be, as it is obvious now,  capturing the variable `terminal` .....and the capturing of `terminal` by definition of `terminal` would require tricks involving `std::function` or so).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's not a recursive function call, look at it step-by-step:

1. `terminal(stdout)` - this simply returns a lambda which has captured `stdout`
2. The result of 1. is called with the lambda `hello`, which executes the lambda (`func(term)`), the result of which is passed to `terminal()`, which simply returns a lambda as in 1.
3. The result of 2. is called with the lambda `world`, which does the same as 2, this time the return value is discarded...

Answer (score 26):

The call itself is not recursive. It returns a function object which, if called, will call `terminal` again to generate yet another function object.

So `terminal(stdout)` returns a functor which captures `stdout` and can be called with another function object. Calling it again, `(hello)`, calls the `hello` functor with the captured term `stdout`, outputting `"Hello"`; the calls `terminal` and returns another functor which this time captures the return value of `hello` - which is still `stdout`. Calling that functor, `(world)`, just the same again, outputting `"World"`.

Comment: Thanks I was going through an article, where the author used with two different lambda, however, I unknowingly tried wrapping it over the original.And found it kinda confusing. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 13):

The key here is to understand that this is valid:

```
world(hello(stdout));
```

and will print "Hello World". The recursive series of lambdas can be unrolled as

```
#include <cstdio>

auto terminal = [](auto term)            // <---------+  
{                                        //           |
    return [=] (auto func)               //           |  ???
    {                                    //           |
        return terminal(func(term));     // >---------+
    };
};

/*
terminal(stdout) -returns> anonymous_lambda which captures stdout (functor)
anonymous_lambda(hello) is called, func(term) is hello(stdout) and prints "Hello" and returns stdout, the anonymous_lambda -returns> terminal(stdout)
(the above 2 lines start again)
terminal(stdout) is called and -returns> anonymous_lambda which captures stdout (functor)
anonymous_lambda(world) is called, func(term) is world(stdout) and prints "World" and returns stdout, the anonymous_lambda -returns> terminal(stdout)
terminal(stdout) is called and -returns> anonymous_lambda which captures stdout (functor)
nobody uses that anonymous_lambda.. end.
*/

auto main() -> int
{
    auto hello =[](auto s){ fprintf(s,"Hello\n"); return s; };
    auto world =[](auto s){ fprintf(s,"World\n"); return s; };

    world(hello(stdout));


    terminal(stdout)
            (hello)
            (world) ;

    return 0;

}
```

[Coliru example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c75be96da4b81b0)

Answer (score 10):

It can be internally translated into something that looks as follows:

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
struct unnamed_lambda
{
    unnamed_lambda(T term) : captured_term(term) {}

    template <typename A>
    unnamed_lambda operator()(A func);

    T captured_term;
};

struct terminal_lambda
{
    template <typename A>
    unnamed_lambda<A> operator()(A term)
    {
        return unnamed_lambda<A>{term};
    }
};

terminal_lambda terminal;

template <typename T>
template <typename A>
unnamed_lambda<T> unnamed_lambda<T>::operator()(A func)
{
    return terminal(func(captured_term));
}

struct Hello
{
    FILE* operator()(FILE* s)
    {
        fprintf(s, "Hello\n");
        return s;
    }
};

struct World
{
    FILE* operator()(FILE* s)
    {
        fprintf(s, "World\n");
        return s;
    }
};

int main()
{    
    Hello hello;
    World world;
    unnamed_lambda<FILE*> l1 = terminal(stdout);
    unnamed_lambda<FILE*> l2 = l1(hello);
    unnamed_lambda<FILE*> l3 = l2(world);

    // same as:
    terminal(stdout)(hello)(world);
}
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://ideone.com/vyJSIO)

Actually this is what the compiler does *behind the scene* with lambdas (with some approximation).

Comment: True (and technically impressive) but irrelevant to the question asked by OP.

Answer (score 8):

I think that the source of confusion comes from reading a lambda declaration as a lambda call. Indeed here:

```
auto terminal = [](auto term)            // <---------+  
{                                        //           |
    return [=] (auto func)               //           |  ???
    {                                    //           |
        return terminal(func(term));     // >---------+
    };
};
```

the author just declared a lambda `terminal` which takes one arbitrary argument `term` and returns an unnamed lambda, nothing more! Let's look at this unnamed lambda, it:

- accepts a callable object `func` as argument and calls it on the copy-captured parameter `term` and
- returns the result of terminal called with the result of the call `func(term)`; so it returns another unnamed lambda that captures the result of `func(term)`, it but this lambda is not called by now, there is no recursion.

Now the trick in the main should be more clear:

1. `terminal(stdout)` returns an unnamed lambda which has captured stdout.
2. `(hello)` calls this unnamed lambda passing as arg the hello callable. This gets called on the stdout previously captured. `hello(stdout)` returns again stdout which is used as argument of a call to terminal, returning another unnamed lambda which has captured stdout.
3. `(world)` same as 2.

Answer (score 3):

1. terminal(stdout) returns a function, let's call it function `x`, with param `func`. So:

   `terminal(stdout) ==> x(func) { return terminal(func(stdout)) };`
2. Now terminal(stdout)(hello) calls function `x(hello)`:

   `terminal(stdout)(hello) ==> x(hello) { return terminal(hello(stdout)) };`

   This results in `hello` function get called and returns function `x` again.
3. Now terminal(std)(hello)(world) calls function `x(world)`:

   `terminal(stdout)(hello) ==> x(world) { return terminal(world(stdout)) };`

   This results in `world` function get called and returns function `x` again. Function `x` now is not called any more as there is no more param.