# "auto" variable used in lambda in its own initializer

Tags: c++, lambda, auto, c++14

Today I found this code

```
#include <cstdio>

auto terminal = [](auto term)           
{                                       
    return [=] (auto func)             
    {                                   
        return terminal(func(term));
    };
};
```

Surprisingly, [GCC accepts it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fac935303911dceb). Clang rejects it because it uses `terminal` in its own intializer and is declared `auto`.

I was expecting the error that clang gave, but is it actually ill-formed? Or must the code be accepted?

Comment: This appears to be making use of polymorphic lambdas which are a feature in C++14. Check to see if your gcc version and / or your Clang version have support for polymorphic lambdas.

Comment: @YoungJohn, The GCC version clearly does if it compiles the code. I can say with confidence that the Clang version on Coliru both supports polymorphic lambdas and does not compile the code.

Comment: @YoungJohn thanks for your advices. I checked GCC and it has support for polymorphic lambdas (as it accepts and executes my snippet). Clang [seems to support them too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e89ece0828ca7484).

Comment: So GCC only seems to complain when I change the function to actually call *both* of those lambdas in the declaration statement and return statement (and comment out the call in `main` because it's no longer compatible at that point).

Comment: @chris can you please show an example?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, [Here you go.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1715a37b1b624774) Unless I'm really out of it, removing either call will make it compile.

Comment: @chris I'm not sure if I'm surprised: once you call the function, you need the return type obviously. In your examples, the return type is dependent if you remove either call, so the return type is not determined after the initialization of `terminal`. I.e. if you only have the outer call, you'll initialize `terminal` with a closure object. The type of this object does not depend on the outer lambda AFAIK. If you only have the inner call, this call is not performed until calling the outer lambda.

Comment: Interestingly, g++ rejects it when the outer lambda is not polymorphic: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9e3ce4f1b2d79da

Comment: I started to post something but then I realized I don't know enough of lambda types... terminal gets initialized with a lambda that returns another lambda, shouldn't that be enough to determine its type?

Comment: For anyone interested, here is the std-discussion mirror of the question: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/PWSmffzcwQ0

Comment: related not really http://stackoverflow.com/q/25618934/560648

Comment: Looks like we need a C++14 tag on this question as well as C++11

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I *think* this runs into §7.1.6.4 [dcl.spec.auto]/p11:

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed
>   to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed.

You need the type of `terminal` to determine the type of the *id-expression* `terminal` in  `return terminal(func(term));` (edited, hat tip @Richard Smith), but at the point of that expression you can't deduce the type of `terminal` yet.

Comment: The return type of the apply-operator is dependent, it must be determined only when instantiating.

Comment: You need the type of `terminal` to determine the type of the *id-expression* `terminal`, so the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Thanks. To summarize: The spec currently is not clear whether `terminal`'s reference to the auto variable must be rejected at the time of definition of the member template `operator()` or accepted at its instantiation (at which time the variable no longer is `auto`). The situation is handled by http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1850 and makes this case ill-formed, according to @RichardSmith's reply on std-discussion