# Return type of function that returns an std::function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std-function

I have a function that should return an std::function of the same type as that function. Basically I want something like this:

```
using RetType = std::function<RetType(void)>;
```

which obviously will not compile. How do I correctly declare the return type?

Comment: does using `auto` work?

Comment: @dwcanillas: Like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25338795/596781)?

Comment: Um, I'm not sure I understand how I would use auto in this case. I have to declare the type and then define this function myself.

Comment: it looks like a truly infinite recursion for me. What if your function returns a function that returns a function etc.?

Comment: @vsoftco Yes it can and it does which should be perfectly legal. Not sure how to tell that to the compiler though

Comment: @SidharthMudgal probably cannot (although I never say never), because C++ is strongly typed, so the compiler must know the type. This of course is my opinion, and not an answer.

Comment: @vsoftco If I can correctly declare the type then why not?

Comment: @SidharthMudgal Well that's the issue, you probably cannot "correctly" declare an infinitely recursive type. But again, let's see what experts on TMP have to say...

Comment: BTW, you would have hard time in C to declare a function returning itself. (or even in Ocaml *without* `-rectypes`)

Comment: Do you want `using RetTypeFunction = std::function<std::function<RetType(void)>(void)>;` ?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `std::function` that way.

You can roll your own, but it will take some work.

Here is a sketch:

```
template<class T, class A, class B>
struct sub{using type=T;};
template<class T, class A, class B>
using sub_t=typename sub<T,A,B>::type;
template<class T, class B>
struct sub<T,T,B>{using type=B;};
template<class R,class...Args,class A,class B>
struct sub<R(Args...),A,B>{
  using type=sub_t<R,A,B>(sub_t<Args,A,B>...);
};
```

write the above.  It takes a type `T`, and if it matches `A` it returns `B`.  Otherwise it returns `T`.  It also works on function signatures.

We can use this with a 'flag' type in a signature to replace with the type of the function object itself:

```
struct recurse{}; // flag type

// not needed in C++14:
template<class Sig>
using result_of_t=typename std::result_of<Sig>::type;

template<class Sig>
struct func {
  using Sig2=sub_t<Sig,recurse,func>;
  using function = std::function<Sig2>;
  function impl;
  template<class...Ts>
  result_of_t<function const&(Ts...)>
  operator()(Ts&&...ts)const
  {
    return impl(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }
};
```

Then `func<recurse()>` is a function object that when called, returns a `func<recurse()>`.

Turns out the implementation is as simple as storing a `std::function<Sig2>` and calling it.  The above code lacks polish -- you'd want constructors, more operators, privacy, etc.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2b60536cad59243)

Note that a y-combinator might be useful if you want to avoid having to capture a copy of yourself by reference in order to return `*this` in a lambda, as capture by reference implies a limited lifetime (and avoid using shared ptr).

Other work that is useful would be enhancing `sub` to handle references-to-`A`, or even templates that contain `A` as an argument.  (the general sub algorithm is not doable in C++, as C++ does not have full meta-template capabilities, but handling every template class currently in `std` is easy: they are all pure type templates, or `std::array`).

---

For completeness, you can add this to `sub`:

```
// optional stuff for completeness:
template<class T,class A,class B>
struct sub<T&,A,B>{
  using type=sub_t<T,A,B>&;
};
template<class T,class A,class B>
struct sub<T*,A,B>{
  using type=sub_t<T,A,B>*;
};
template<template<class...>class Z,class... Ts,class A,class B>
struct sub<Z<Ts...>,A,B>{
  using type=Z<sub_t<Ts,A,B>...>;
};
template<template<class,size_t>class Z,class T,size_t n,class A,class B>
struct sub<Z<T,n>,A,B>{
  using type=Z<sub_t<T,A,B>,n>;
};
template<class T,size_t n,class A,class B>
struct sub<T[n],A,B>{
  using type=sub_t<T,A,B>[n];
};
template<class T,class A,class B>
struct sub<T[],A,B>{
  using type=sub_t<T,A,B>[];
};
template<class T,class A,class B>
struct sub<T const,A,B>{
  using type=sub_t<T,A,B> const;
};
template<class T,class A,class B>
struct sub<T volatile const,A,B>{
  using type=sub_t<T,A,B> volatile const;
};
template<class T,class A,class B>
struct sub<T volatile,A,B>{
  using type=sub_t<T,A,B> volatile;
};
```

And it now works recursively on many templates, on arrays, references, and pointers, and with cv-qualified types.  This allows you to write something like:

```
func< std::vector<recurse>() >
```

which is a function object whose `operator()` returns a `func< std::vector<recurse>() >`.

Note that this procedure isn't quite perfect, as if `some_template<recurse>` isn't a valid template instantiation, the above won't work.  A stranger version that takes potentially applied templates and arguments, does the substitution, then the application, would be required in such cases.