# How can I "map" a parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

This question is similar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338795/is-there-a-name-for-this-tuple-creation-idiom), It seems in my version I need to write my own `sizeof...`

Suppose I have a struct `Wrapper` with definition

```
struct Wrapper{
    string s;
}
```

and I have a function, it accept a pack of `Wrapper` and `printf` them. Because `printf` take a pack of `const char *`, so I need to map this pack of `Wrapper` into a pack of `const char *`

```
template<typename ... Args>
void printf_wrapper(string format, Args&& ... args){
    printf(format.c_str(), /* #1: WHAT CAN I WRITE HERE */)
}
```

I heard a `swallow` function may help me with that, but what does it like, and how it functions?

Comment: `printf(format.c_str(), wrapper_to_string(args).c_str()...);`?

Comment: With C++17 comes [*fold expressions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) which allows you to use standard C++ streams (see example in the reference) which will make it much safer. The `printf` function is very troublesome in C++, and of course have safety issue C++ streams doesn't have (think about user-inputted format strings (way to common unfortunately) and what they might do if the arguments doesn't match).

Comment: There are of course ways to handle output of parameter packs using streams before C++17 too. The example `tprintf` function [in this parameter pack reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) shows you one way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the wrapper you defined in the question, it's a matter of using this:

```
template<typename ... Args>
void printf_wrapper(std::string format, Args&& ... args){
    printf(format.c_str(), args.s.c_str()...);
}
```

As a minimal, working example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

struct Wrapper{
    std::string s;
};

template<typename... T>
constexpr bool areWrappers =
    std::is_same<
        std::integer_sequence<bool, true, std::is_same<T, Wrapper>::value...>,
        std::integer_sequence<bool, std::is_same<T, Wrapper>::value..., true>
    >::value;

template<typename ... Args>
void printf_wrapper(std::string format, Args&& ... args){
    static_assert(areWrappers<std::decay_t<Args>...>, "!");
    printf(format.c_str(), args.s.c_str()...);
}

int main() {
    printf_wrapper("%s %s", Wrapper{"foo"}, Wrapper{"bar"});
}
```

I added also the `areWrappers` utility to check that your `Args` are actually all `Wrapper`s. If they are not, the solution above won't work, but the `static_assert` will help to get out of it a meaningful error message.

---

See it on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SFQQXDiQEC5qaRyn).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a simple solution which is similar to @ildjarn's posted in the comment above.

If the `Wrapper` structure looks like this:

```
struct Wrapper {
    std::string hidden_str;
};
```

Then you might change the print function as below:

```
template<typename... Args>
void print(const std::string& format, Args const&... args) {
    printf(format.c_str(), args.hidden_str.c_str()...);
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1Kq1foafB5hUxg6M)