# Language feature to apply function to each element of a parameter pack

Tags: c++, standards, variadic-templates, c++17

Does anyone know, if there exists a standards proposal for a c++ language feature that would allow me to replace this (thanks to Yakk):

```
template<class... ARGS>
void bar(const ARGS& ... args) {        
    auto t = { (foo(args),0)... };
    (void) t; //<- prevent warning about unused variable
}
```

with something more natural like this:

```
template<class... ARGS>
void bar(const ARGS& ... args) {        
    foo(args)...;
}
```

`foo` being e.g. a function, a function template and/or an overloaded set of those, whose return type might be void (or in general which I don't care about).

Btw, if someone knows a more concise way to write this in c++14, feel free to share, but I think, this is already handled in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030538/calling-a-function-for-each-variadic-template-argument-and-an-array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) with the comma operator:

```
( void(foo(args)) , ...);
```

I didn't see any proposal to change this further in recent mailings.

Comment: That is indeed a nice feature - has this already been voted into the next standard or is it only proposed?