# how to call member functions when the objects is variable template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

how to call member functions when the objects is variable template parameters? Here's a example:

```
template <typename ...A>
void f(A... args)
{
    args->memfunc("examples")...; // the code not right!
}
```

How to do it right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030538/calling-a-function-for-each-variadic-template-argument-and-an-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++17, you can use a [fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template <typename ...A>
void f(A... args)
{
    (..., args->memfunc("examples")); // the code not right!
}
```

Comment: Hi, I used your code in c++17. However, It can't be compiled.

Comment: In function ‘flow_graph::SharedFuture<T> flow_graph::lift_mx(std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>, flow_graph::SharedFuture<A>...)’:
/home/mx/libraries/flow-graph/src/flow_graph.hpp:446:4: error: expected primary-expression before ‘...’ token
   (..., args->listen(continuation));

Comment: @mxmxlwlw Then your compiler does not implement the entire C++17 spec. [See this demo where it does work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81b50dd6861d2b2b)

Comment: yeah... you are right!

Answer (score 4):

That's rather tricky. A parameter pack can be expanded only in certain contexts. You can't just write a statement expanding it (without C++17 fold expressions). The usual trick involves using a dummy array initializer (which is a possible context with well defined evaluation order):

```
int dummy[] = { // Expand it in the initializer
  (void(args->memfunc("examples")), 0)...
};
```

We don't want to force a specific return type on all the members. So we use the comma operator `(..., 0)` to create an expression that always has an `int` type. However, since operators can be overloaded we need to cast the result of the function call to void in order to make sure we use the built-in one. So the expression we expand ends up being what you see.